# Carousel not displaying images on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a carousel which is working fine. But when I try to reduce the height of the carousel, the whole image is not being displayed in the carousel (on desktop). On mobile it works fine.

I don't want the carousel to cover the whole page.
Please see the output in full screen.

**Example:**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
 #carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .item {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .first-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/13/1359503.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .second-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://all4desktop.com/data_images/1920%20x%201200/4211692-abstract-color-background-picture-8016.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .third-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Abstract/Mac%20Wallpaper%20Spin%20The%20Apple%20Circle-575024442.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide slid" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active first-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item second-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item third-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It takes up the full screen. You don't want that to happen or what?

Comment: @shannon Ha ha. Looks like the issue is figured out. He doesn't want it to take up full width when in huge screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following CSS sets a `max-width`, after which it is width limited proportionally with the height:

```css
#carousel-example-generic {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/revecireyu/1**

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post. I have tried changes suggested by you. But I want the width to be 100% and I don't want the height to be 100%.But  if I change the width, even the height changes.

Comment: @SriHarsha That's why it is proportional to the image bro!

Comment: I have understood it.Thank you for helping me.

Comment: That was by mistake.